# How print out numbers for multiples of 3 that divide without a remainder numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

How can I print out numbers for multiples of 3 that divide without a remainder numbers?

I am attempting to get `3`, `6`, and `9` in array but only `1` prints out, my syntax could be wrong.

```js
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
for (var  i = 0; i % 3 === 0; i++) {
  console.log (numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: your loop stops once the condition (i % 3 === 0) is false - you need an `if` statement in the body of the loop instead

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me understand, I’m just starting out so I need a lot of clarification. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. When this `i % 3 === 0` check fails your loop stops.
2. You should check whether the elements(`numbers[i]`) of your array are divisible by 3, not the indices(`i`).

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (numbers[i] % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand more about for loop.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Code Some think like that:

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];

for (var  i = 0; i <= 10 ; i++) {
  if(numbers[i] % 3 === 0){
    console.log (numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];

for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
  if( i % 3 === 0 ) {
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const res = numbers.forEach((el) => {
  if (el % 3 === 0) {
    console.log(el);
  }
});
```

just one more way to do it using forEach.
LOGIC -
If the number is divisible by three then it is a multiple of 3. Try testing to see if when the number is divided by 3 there is a remainder using the modulus operator

Comment: Thank you brother, I have tried the forEach method and it does work. I was trying to use the for loop for practice. I appreciate your hard work and guidance.